# jQuery クロスドメインのAjaxでエラーになってしまいます。

Tags: php, ajax

クロスドメインでjsを実行するためにlocalhostでテスト中です。

html側

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:Url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success : function (res) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error : function(res){
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

php側

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
echo json_encode( 123456789 );
```

上記コードを実行すると `"error"` というダイアログが表示されます。
一番シンプルな形にしているつもりですが、どこに原因があるのかつかません。
echo を文字列にしたり、配列にしたりしてみましたが状況変わらずでした。

`dataType: "jsonp` を削除すると`"success"`が表示されます。

アドバイスお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

php側の実装はJSONPではなくJSONですね。

JSONPなら

```
callback(123456789);
```

というJavaScriptを返すべきです。

Answer (score 0):

下記のようにすることで動作しました。アドバイス感謝です。

html側

```
    jQuery.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url:Url,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      jsonpCallback: 'callback',
      success : function (res) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error : function(res){
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

php側

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
echo "callback(".json_encode( "123456789" ).")";
```